# CakePHP ACL without prefixed methods

Tags: php, methods, routes, acl, cakephp-2.0

When developping applications in CakePHP I came to the conclussion that there's a lot of redundant data when using prefixes such as admin, moderator etc.

When Googling around for a bit, I found a reply by zuha-3 http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Going-back-to-school-ACL-td4941972.html#a4949876

> In our app we keep prefix routing but get rid of the method routing. 
>   So we still get the `$this->params->params['prefix']` but route the user
>   to the `index()` method instead of the `admin_index()` method.   We then
>   leave it up to ACL completely to decide whether your role has access
>   to the index function.   This allows us to get rid of 50% of the view
>   files and 50% of the controller methods.
>
> We can have different views for different user roles in that we assign
>   view prefixes to user roles.  So we can have an admin view, and all
>   users in the admin user role would see
>   /Posts/View/Posts/admin/index.ctp instead of
>   /Posts/View/Posts/index.ctp if and only if the admin view exists.  We
>   could do the same thing for managers, users, etc, and leave it up to
>   each app to decide whether managers would see the admin view or the
>   manager view or the guest view.

So this would take out a lot of the redundant methods.

Does anyone has some sort of follow op post in this mater or useful information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just create routes like this:

```
Router::connect('/admin/users/index', array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

And then you would need an index.ctp view, rather then an admin_index.ctp one. But I'm not really sure why that would add anything to your application. Admin views usually have their own specific function (like grant access to adding/deleting users once the user's clearance to do this has been verified) and should therefor be seperate from the 'regular' views. (Otherwise you'll get very messy views with admin verification logic, which isn't really much of an MVC app, that stuff belongs in a controller.)

**EDIT:** According to your comment below, I would just render the admin view from your mod method and set some flags to determine what they can and cannot do/see. For example:

```
function mod_index() {
    $this->set('can_edit_users', 1);
    $this->set('can_delete_users', 0);

    // User admin_index view, rather then looking for mod_index view
    $this->render('admin_index');
}
```

And then in your views add simple checks to determine what links/information they can and cannot see.

Comment: For example I have admin en moderators, their rights are almost simulair to eachother, but rather than creating two methods with exactly the same logic in side is redundant. it also gets worst if you need to submit changes. The views can be completly different.

I think I just want the best of both...

Comment: Edited answer according to your comment.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that works for index pages. Even determining what links to display or not is a good idea. But you still have the same problem of having two (or more) methods in your controller doing to same things. But by rethinking it over and over the changes require much more core work... I think the idea works as this: example.com/prefix/controller/action > will map to controller::prefix_action, with the view prefix_action.ctp. But if it's possible to check if the method exists than go default mapping else take the other, all autonomic?

Comment: If it's the methods you're worried about, you can still use routes to route /mod/action to /admin/action and then use something like $this->params->url to determine if /admin or /mod was used to get to your method.

Comment: Yes that is possible as well, I'll give it a shot! Thanks for the help